# Auto permissions for new files in folder for NGINX to read

Tags: linux, nginx, debian, debian-stretch

I have a mysql database that is generating new log files every few hours in /var/www/html folder using such command -

```
SELECT * FROM logs.today INTO OUTFILE '/var/www/html/todayslogs.csv';
```

And this is how the generated file looks (LOGS.csv)
[image]

I have tried running -

```
chmod g+s /var/www/html
```

But nginx still can't read the files that are created by mysql, please help, thank you!

P.s I am running debian 4.19.181-1

Answer (score 0):

Well ... making the group ownership "sticky" won't help you much if the group is `root` and `www-data` isn't a member of it.

I wouldn't recommend adding the nginx user to that group, though, so your safest bet would be to modify the group ownership of the generated logs to `www-data`.